# How do I change the background colour of a <label> if a checkbox is checked, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery, is there a more efficient way of writing this code? See below

The JQuery:

```
$("#ex1").live("click", function(){
if($("#ex1").attr("checked")==true){ 
    $(this).parent().removeClass("im-unchecked").addClass("im-checked"); 
}
else if($("#ex1").attr("checked")==false){ 
    $(this).parent().removeClass("im-checked").addClass("im-unchecked");
}});


$("#ex2").live("click", function(){
if($("#ex2").attr("checked")==true){ 
    $(this).parent().removeClass("im-unchecked").addClass("im-checked"); 
}
else if($("#ex2").attr("checked")==false){ 
    $(this).parent().removeClass("im-checked").addClass("im-unchecked"); 
}});
```

The HTML I'm working with:

```
<label for="ex1" id="ex-label-1">Y <input type="checkbox" id="ex1" name="ex" value="Y" <% If IsEx("Y") then%>checked<%end if%> /></label>
<label for="ex2" id="ex-label-2">M <input type="checkbox" id="ex2" name="ex" value="M" <% If IsEx("M") then%>checked<%end if%> /></label>
<label for="ex5" id="ex-label-3">X <input type="checkbox" id="ex5" name="ex" value="X" <% If IsEx("X") then %>checked<%end if%> /></label>
<label for="ex3" id="ex-label-4">N <input type="checkbox" id="ex3" name="ex" value="N" <% If IsEx("N") then %>checked<%end if%> /></label>
<label for="ex6" id="ex-label-5">L <input type="checkbox" id="ex6" name="ex" value="L" <% If IsEx("L") then %>checked<%end if%> /></label>
<label for="ex7" id="ex-label-6">Z <input type="checkbox" id="ex7" name="ex" value="Z" <% If IsEx("Z") then %>checked<%end if%> /></label>
<label for="ex4" id="ex-label-7">A <input type="checkbox" id="ex4" name="ex" value="A" <% If IsEx("A") then %>checked<%end if%> /></label>
```

Sorry guys I'm a novice as JavaScript/JQuery

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `name` attribute selector and cut down on the code using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) like this:

```
$("input[name='ex']:checkbox").live("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("im-unchecked", !this.checked)
                  .toggleClass("im-checked", this.checked); 
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Jdu6c/).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just add a class to each checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="ex" id="ex1" name="ex" value="Y" <% If IsEx("Y") then%>checked<%end if%> />
```

and use that instead of id's (and you can also use some selectors like :checked in place of `attr('checked') == true`)

```
$(".ex").live("click", function(){
 var cb = $(this);
if(cb.is(':checked')){ 
    cb.parent().removeClass("im-unchecked").addClass("im-checked"); 
}
else{ 
    cb.parent().removeClass("im-checked").addClass("im-unchecked");
}});
```

EDIT: Fixed typo in above code. And added obligatory jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X6jxL/